# How Can I Intelligently Implement Auto-Resizing in a Visual C# Winforms App?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

My application (which I am using Visual C# 2008 WinForms for) involves a lot of generated controls. Specifically: grids of buttons, arrays of labels, lists, headings, etc... all populated so that they fit their containers appreciably.

I want users to be able to resize the main form, which obviously would require me to either destroy my generated content, and remake it at the proper size OR I could index through every control, figure out what it is by name and type, and re-size each item individually. I would have to do this while/after the form resizes.

Are there any more intelligent ways of doing this? Dock and Anchor don't quite apply here because I am dealing with items that don't make up 100% of a dimension (for example, grids of buttons).

Comment: I think docking and anchoring are still useful here, but maybe if you could post a screenshot of your form we could give you some pointers. WinForms is old technology, and it has it's limitations.

Comment: It's the old story, intelligent resize behavior requires intelligent code in the OnResize overload.  There's plenty that Winforms can do but the more intricate the window layout, the less likely that will work for you.

Comment: @JMK I could post a screenshot, but consider the simple example of a 4x4 grid of buttons. This already isn't scalable with docking/anchoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard do give a reasonnable answer without seing just how complex the layout in question is.

But in principle, you should use a layout container such as `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` to do the job they were designed to do. If one does not do the job, just nest them.

Comment: This look promising. Do either of those panels allow their contents to scale/fill the panel, or is it just a stacking assistant?

Comment: You can use `Dock` as well as standard `AnchorStyles` properties for each control inside the cells of the Panels.

Comment: What does one of your typical layout look like? Could tell you how I would try to lay it out with those containers.

Comment: The 3x3 or 4x4 button grid examples resize perfectly within a `TableLayoutPanel` for example, just dock the buttons, set the row and columns to relative sizes and you are done.

Comment: This is basically what I want to do. My typical layout includes a 6x5 (or similar) grid of buttons. I had never known about layout panels. Basically all I need to do is make the panel the correct size, put the buttons in them, dock each one, and away I go.

Answer (score 0):

Docking/anchoring is probably the answer here. You need to anchor your grid to top/bottom/left/right or dock it (same effect, but the grid will fill the parent control).

If this is done right your control(s) will re-size with the rest of the form just as if you created everything in the designer.

I believe something like this would work:

`Control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.TopLeft | AnchorStyles.BottomRight;`

Comment: Build a 3 x 3 grid of buttons, then resize. They don't scale *and* maintain their spacing.